# Change Text of the Button in Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I really stuck in a simple operation :-/

I have a number of section to swipe left / right as an Adapter / ViewPager, number of pages are defined dynamically during run-time.

There is button in the page which caption I would like to change during run time.

Of' cause Android is creating several pages in once to cash them and speed up scrolling. This leads to the problem that if I just look for a button using findViewById and change the caption, this change will be applied for the next screen, and not for the current visible one.

I can get the number of currently displayed ViewPager by .getCurrentItem but I cannot understand how I can address the very this button which is currently on screen.

Would be happy for any advice!

p.s. Sorry that I do not attach the code, it's quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Change the text in an OnPageChangeListener with [addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)).

Comment: Thanks. I have a bit different situatio: there is a button and textview  once button is pressed, text should be changed